# What does it mean when it says "Volle Suppe"?

Tags: idiom

Is "Volle Suppe" a German idiom? And how would that translate into English?

Answer (score 6):

> Volle Suppe!

and similarly

> Volle Kanne!

means something like:

> [Balls to the wall!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=balls%20to%20the%20wall)

or

> [Full tilt!](http://www.dict.cc/?s=full+tilt)

Comment: Nice, I just knew "Volle Kanne!", never heard the soup version.

Answer (score -1):

Also used (mostly in the North and usually in context with bikes) "Volles Rohr!"

Comment: OP asked for a translation into English. You're providing a German alternative…